# Что нужно дописать в запросе ? sql (PostgreSQL 14)

Tags: sql, postgresql

столкнулся с такой проблемой, есть запрос в таблицу:

```
SELECT source, object, hostname, ip_addres, Status, mac_address, serial_number, worker, owner, redirect, plata_no_repair, plata_removed, model, comment 
FROM svodka1 EXCEPT 
SELECT source, object, hostname, ip_addres, Status, mac_address, serial_number, worker, owner, redirect, plata_no_repair, plata_removed, model, comment  
FROM svodka2
```

Он проверят отличие с 1 таблицей и со 2 таблицей. Но Есть точно такая же 3 таблица с такими столбцами. И мне надо в нее записывались результаты( я так понял при помощи UPDATE). Но я запутался и  не пойму что надо в конце дописать чтобы все это заработало.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Работаю с mySQL, там бы (если бы он `EXCEPT` поддерживал) я сделал так, как ниже, - просто вписал бы в таблицу svodka3 таблицу с получившимися результатами. В принципе, должен и на PostgreSQL 14 такой вариант отработать, проверьте.
По крайней мере, [документации](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/14/sql-insert) не противоречит.

```
INSERT INTO svodka3 (source, object, hostname, ip_addres, Status, mac_address, serial_number, worker, owner, redirect, plata_no_repair, plata_removed, model, comment) 
/*Ниже - ваш текст без изменений, только в скобках на случай конфликта с EXCEPT*/
(SELECT source, object, hostname, ip_addres, Status, mac_address, serial_number, worker, owner, redirect, plata_no_repair, plata_removed, model, comment 
FROM svodka1 EXCEPT 
SELECT source, object, hostname, ip_addres, Status, mac_address, serial_number, worker, owner, redirect, plata_no_repair, plata_removed, model, comment  
FROM svodka2)
```

Через `UPDATE + SET` больше возни, на мой взгляд.

Comment: Не работает, проблема с синтаксисом :(

Comment: вопрос почему мы INSERT INTO в начале пишем ?

Comment: Мы INSERT INTO в начале пишем согласно синтаксису (см. уже приведенную мной ссылку в ответе) и согласно логике - даем понять, что потом пойдет то, что вставлять надо. Например, таблицу или `VALUES` по одному.

Comment: А что за проблема с синтаксисом, из-за которой не работает? У вас таблица в результате EXCEPT получается со всеми полями, как в svodka3 или там, например, полей меньше?

Comment: в конце ; не поставил. Все решилось, Cпасибо!